# What Factors Determine the Number of Page Fault

Tags: ubuntu, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, framebuffer, beagleboneblack

I've been developing a USB frame buffer driver for BeagleBone Black. The driver works on the concept of Page Fault. Each time there is a Page Fault it reads the Page and send it over USB to the device. If the number of page fault is too high, there will be a lot of data to pass over USB and the USB bandwidth may not be able to pass that much data in time.

If I test my driver on BeagleBoard, I see around 21000 page fault for a 7 seconds video file. But for same driver and same video file, I get around 5600 page fault in Ubuntu in my Dell Laptop with Intel CPU. At first I though my Ubuntu machine has more RAM(4GB) compared to the BeagleBone(512 MB) which causes the small number of page fault in Ubuntu.

So to make sure, I created a virtual machine with Ubuntu installed and 512 MB RAM, and tested the same driver and video file with it. I was surprised to see that on the VM, the number of Page Fault is still the same 5600.

So I did create some more VM's and tested on all of those and in every case the number of page fault was 5600. I tested on Arch Linux, multiple version of Debian. In every case the number of page fault was 5600.

So finally I moved my code in a new hardware(AMD CPU) and different version of Ubuntu and same number of page fault occurs in that one.

Also to make things easier, I didn't run any other program during testing or didn't install any service. Also page size in all the hardwares or VM's were same: 4096 bytes

So I would like to know some factors which might be responsible for increase in number of page faults in BeagleBone, whereas it is exactly same in all other machines. I thought it should at least differ by a little amount in different machines, which was not happening.

Comment: What's the page size of the beaglebone board vs x86?

Comment: Page_Size in all the hardwares or VM's were same: 4096 bytes